# Trying to create watermark in Acrobat Pro XI based off of user prompts for multiple docs

Tags: prompt, acrobat, watermark

Hopefully I have this in the correct forum.  I am trying to add a script to prompt a user for 3 pieces of information then create a watermark.  This information will change for every user that wishes to open and print the document.  I also need to apply this to numerous (currently about 2,000) documents, and that number will increase as our engineers generate new blueprints.  I know 2,000 is a lot to process at once, but if I could batch this into groups of 100 or so that would still make things much easier than doing a single document at a time.  I am unable to download any third-party software to accomplish this so I am looking for a solution within Acrobat Pro XI.  I have created an action with the action wizard that uses document javascript, then saves the newly watermarked file to the local user computer.  I have tried performing this as a batch with multiple files, but I am require to re-enter the script with each document.

Is there a way to do this and apply it to multiple files only having to copy and past the script one time?  Below is a copy of the code that I have so far.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function Watermark()
{
}

var dialogTitle = "Please Complete";

var string1 = "This PDF has been created for";
var defaultAnswer = "";

var string2 = app.response("Add Employee Name",
dialogTitle, defaultAnswer);

var string3 = app.response("Add JON",
dialogTitle, defaultAnswer);

var string4 = app.response("Add Work Order Number",
dialogTitle, defaultAnswer);

var string5 = "Valid for use ONLY on this work order.";
var defaultAnswer = "";

var cMyText = string1 +"\n"+ string2 +", JON "+ string3 +", Work Order "+ string4 +"\n"+ string5;

this.addWatermarkFromText({
    cText: cMyText,
    nHorizAlign:app.constants.align.left,
    nHorizValue: 650,
    nVertAlign: app.constants.align.bottom,
    nVertValue: 160,
    cFont: "Helvetica-Bold",
    nFontSize:22,
    aColor: ["RGB", 255, 0, 0],
    nRotation:0,
    nOpacity: 0.7,
    bOnTop:false,
});
```

Comment: You should really implement this as an Acrobat Custom Command. That way you don't need to inject it into each document. The Watermark script will just appear in the UI after you distribute the Custom Command. I'd also suggest that you modify your script to produce a single AcroDialog that collects the three pieces of information rather than use the app.response() method.

Comment: @Joelgeraci, thanks for the quick answer.  I'm not familiar with either the Acrobat Custom Command or the AcroDialog, so I'll see what info I can find about them.  Are the fairly intuitive to use?  If you have time and would be able to give me a few steps to point me in the right direction to achieve this, that would be amazing.  Thanks again.

Comment: The URL below shows how to create a Custom Command that adds a watermark. You can also easily export and distribute custom commands to other users once you've tested it.

https://blogs.adobe.com/documentcloud/hidden-gems-in-acrobat-dc-create-custom-commands/